# django paypal_ipn table does not exist

Tags: django, django-paypal, django-migrations

I am trying to implement django-paypal (dcramer's version) with IPN and although I get the notification, it is answered with a 500 error. I checked my debug log and I saw this message:

`DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'myproject.paypal_ipn' doesn't exist")`

none of the tutorials I have found mentioned anything about pypal_ipn table. I also did a syncdb and a south migrate but the table is not created.

What am I doing wrong?

this is what I get with a syncdb:

```
Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > debug_toolbar
 > grappelli
 > filebrowser
 > tinymce
 > south
 > avatar
 > django.contrib.admin
 > notification

Not synced (use migrations):
 - paypal.standard.ipn

$ python manage.py schemamigration main --auto
Nothing seems to have changed.
$ python manage.py migrate main
Running migrations for main:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for main.
No fixtures found.
```

Comment: Try "python manage.py migrate". That should migrate the paypal app too.

Comment: right. I am too tired. I need to go home and come back tomorrow... :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. :) I moved the comment to an answer so you may close the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `python manage.py migrate`. That should migrate the paypal app too.

(Moved from comment to here so the question may be closed. Apparently this did the trick.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to migrate the app explicitly

```
python manage.py migrate paypal.standard.ipn
```

Answer (score 0):

If Mike S' solution doesn't work just migrate ipn (this is what worked for me)

```
python manage.py migrate ipn
```